# How to create multiple Actors in AKKA by a loop in java?

Tags: java, akka, actor

this is just a learning example, I wan't to create and assign a actor for each element in an array,

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("mySystem");
for(String name:namesArray){
  ActorRef myActor = system.actorOf(Props.create(Actor.class),name);
}
```

Will this create multiple actor or will it create actor paths that reference to the same actor? if its the latter how do i create multiple actors and assign them a identifier?

Comment: why not try it out?

Comment: this is my very first time in AKKA, i actually dont know how to test it, my objective is to create a set number actors (to big to hardcode) hope you can help me out here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code will:

- Create an `ActorSystem`
- Create an actor for every name in the `namesArray` (it will throw an `InvalidActorNameException` if a name appears a second time in the array)

Note that this code as written promptly forgets the `ActorRef` for every one of the created actors, meaning that you would not be able to send it a message except by using `ActorSelection` which is generally not recommended.  Going along with this, it's worth noting that the actor will continue running even if there are no `ActorRef`s for that actor (actors must be explicitly stopped).

Comment: Thankyou so much, if it's not too much can you explain why ActorSelection is bad? and what workaround could i use to create multiple actors without using ActorSelection?

Comment: In general, using `ActorSelection` is more fragile (as messages sent to a nonexistent address will be dropped). Using the `ActorRef` to send messages is more reliable (you can at least be sure if you have an `ActorRef` that there actually was an actor to receive the message (it might have since stopped, but that's a different class of bug from what you get with using `ActorSelection`).  You can save the `ActorRef`s in collections (e.g. a `Map<String, ActorRef>`) and send them in messages.

Comment: Another alternative which is useful in many cases is to use cluster sharding to manage actors of a given type: this allows (especially in conjunction with persistence) actors to be migrated (in a balance-preserving way) across a cluster and will automatically spawn an actor for a given ID if none exists (it's only in certain fairly rare operational scenarios that a cluster sharded actor won't exist when you need it).